# sed won't delete what I want

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I am writing a bash shell script, and in it I am trying to delete lines from a text file between 2 markers

```
START
...
...
END
```

Do eliminate this I have tried a few things, and every time it leave my text file blank.

`sed '/START/,/END/d' myfile.txt > myfile.txt`

`sed '/START/d' myfile.txt > myfile.txt`

As long as I have a sed command in my code, my entire file gets erased and not just the section I am looking to erase.

Comment: It is a duplicate, but I could not for the life of me find that question when I was searching because I wasn't searching for the right keywords. But its all fixed now. Thank you

Comment: The duplicate stated isn't a duplicate, the problem op is having is it overwriting after the command(which im almost usre is also a dup)

Answer (score 4):

You are redirecting `stdout` to the same file as `stdin`.  When you do this, your redirection is interpreted buy the shell and it opens a new file for write with that name.  Your existing file is overwritten by the newly created blank file.  You will need to redirect the output to a different file or you can edit the file by using the `-i` option to `sed`.

Comment: I did this before and it didn't work. But now that I have changed the output file it works perfectly. I could not get the `-i` flag to work at all. I would get an error at that stated that the first letter of the filename was an incorrect command.

Anyway it is working now, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can't redirect to a file that you are reading. That will delete your file's contents, as you've noticed.

Instead, either redirect to a different file, or edit in place:

```
sed -i ... myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

A way in awk.

```
awk '/START/{x=1}/END/{x=0}!x{print > ARGV[1]}' myfile.txt
```

Portable

```
awk '/START/{x=1}/END/{x=0}!x{print > "myfile.txt"}' myfile.txt
```